# Send image to server through js fetch

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch

I am changing my form submission to make it more fluid via using fetch.

In order to process the value of my input image:

`<input name="perfil" type='file' id="imageUpload />`

And then, in order to upload it to Amazon S3,

I do this in my views.py:

```
if request.method == "POST"
    image = request.FILES['perfil']

    im = Image.open(image)

    output = BytesIO()

    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    rgb_im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=90)
    output.seek(0)
            
    s3.Bucket('bucketname').upload_fileobj(output, request.user.email + '.profileImage')
```

But now (because i'm trying to implement fetch), I am getting the image file like this:

```
fetch(`url`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    image: document.querySelector('#imageUpload').files[0],
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
  }
})

}
```

The problem is that when I do `` request.body['image`] `` in the server (views.py), all I'm getting is this: `"image":{}`

And I don't know how to process this file in JS before I send it to the server (that will end up  uploading it to amazon s3)

Answer (score 1):

With this Example you can upload Images on a Server!

```
// Select your input type file and store it in a variable
const input = document.getElementById('fileinput');

// This will upload the file after having read it
const upload = (file) => {
  fetch('http://www.example.net', { // Your POST endpoint
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      // Content-Type may need to be completely **omitted**
      // or you may need something
      "Content-Type": "You will perhaps need to define a content-type here"
    },
    body: file // This is your file object
  }).then(
    response => response.json() // if the response is a JSON object
  ).then(
    success => console.log(success) // Handle the success response object
  ).catch(
    error => console.log(error) // Handle the error response object
  );
};

// Event handler executed when a file is selected
const onSelectFile = () => upload(input.files[0]);

// Add a listener on your input
// It will be triggered when a file will be selected
input.addEventListener('change', onSelectFile, false);
```